# Cumulative Difference with initial value

Tags: sql, oracle

Computing the cumulative difference between the previous and current row values

This is regarding to production. The qty_needed, and qty_onhand are given values acquired in database. I wanted to replace the values displayed in qty_onhand with a cumulative difference result since it displayed repetitively because it is a join query. Hope that you can help me with this matter.

Sample running displayed data.

```
qty_needed      qty_onhand
5                 10                  
5                 10
5                 10
```

To get the remaining_onhand column here is the sample.

initial value of qty_onhand = 10.

> formula: qty_needed - previous_qty_onhand

```
qty_needed          qty_onhand
    5                 10                  
    5                 10-5 = 5
    5                 5-5 = 0

SAMPLE SCRIPT:

CASE 
WHEN ROW_NUMBER () 
OVER (PARTITION BY component 
ORDER BY partno) = 
1 
THEN 
qty_on_hand 
WHEN qty_on_hand - SUM (qty_needed) 
OVER (PARTITION BY component ORDER BY partno ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) <= 0 
THEN 
0 
ELSE 
qty_on_hand - SUM (qty_needed) 
OVER (PARTITION BY component ORDER BY partno ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
END AS testQtyNeeded
```

Comment: Please update your question and add a valid simple data, I see you are using two additional columns `component` & `partno` but they are missing in simple data

Comment: `max(qty_onhand) - sum(qty_needed) over(order by some_order_criteria)` Also please note that SQL table has no inherent order and it's not clear what should be considered as *the first* in your sample data (however, it's poor because it repeats the same row three times and do not cover any edge cases). Please update your question with enough sample data and a description of calculation rules

Comment: Looks like you need [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/HbyBJamZ).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help. It actually work outside the WITH clause but when I input it in WITH clause, it shows wrong calculation. It doesn't recognize the initial value and directly subtract the data.

Answer (score 0):

For repeatable results you are going to need some consistent logic to order the rows. Here I have assigned a row number using `over(order by 1)` which isn't guaranteed to exactly match the order rows were inserted it but usually is close to that. Ideally you would have some other columns (some dates perhaps?) that could be used instead. Then assuming you want to figure out when to re-order this approach may help:

```
WITH assign_rn
AS (
    SELECT data.*
        , row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY 1
            ) AS rn
        , sum(qty_needed) OVER (
            PARTITION BY component ORDER BY 1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 preceding
            ) cum_needed
    FROM data
    )
SELECT partno
    , component
    , rn
    , qty_needed
    , qty_on_hand
    , qty_on_hand - cum_needed qty_after_use
    , CASE WHEN qty_on_hand - cum_needed <= 0 THEN 're-order' ELSE NULL END AS note
FROM assign_rn
ORDER BY component
    , rn
```

| PARTNO | COMPONENT | RN | QTY_NEEDED | QTY_ON_HAND | QTY_AFTER_USE | NOTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | AX | 1 | 5 | 10 | 5 | *null* |
| 103 | AX | 2 | 5 | 10 | 0 | re-order |
| 102 | AX | 3 | 5 | 10 | -5 | re-order |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6ow_x8vo)

nb: normally there would also be some data available about re-order levels but that can be introduced into the case expression seen above should such data exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sum() OVER() analytic function to calculate running sum of needed quantity.

```sql
Select  NEEDED, ONHAND,
        ONHAND - Nvl(Sum(NEEDED) OVER(Partition By 1 Order By 1 Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 0) "ONHAND_CALC" 
From tbl
```

... which with your sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl (NEEDED, ONHAND) AS
        (
            Select 5, 10 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 10 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 10 From Dual
        )
```

... results as:

```sql
    NEEDED     ONHAND ONHAND_CALC
---------- ---------- -----------
         5         10          10 
         5         10           5 
         5         10           0
```

NOTE: the *(Partition By 1 Order By 1)* should be adjusted to meet your needs. You probably have something to partition and order the rows by.